# Keeping centered image out of non centered parent element

Tags: html, css

I was given a help here on stackoverflow but when I applied it on my code it did not work as it should have.

I tried so many things but I didn´t find out how to keep images center in "column" (as they are now) but with text align to left.

How can I do it?
If I remove `margin: 0 auto` from `div.table-wrap` text alings back to left (like it should) but it moves with the image.. I would like to have the image fixed on right side and centered withing that "image column"

```css
div.table-wrap {
  display: table;
 width: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

div.table-wrap div {
  display: table-row;
}

div.table-wrap ul {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.table-wrap ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

div.table-wrap ul li.titulek {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.00em;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

div.table-wrap a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

div.table-wrap a img {
  height: 150px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrap">
<div>
<ul>
<li class="titulek">- Mazné šroubové kompresory systém zatíženo – odlehčeno, typ <b>ESM 2 -500</b></li>
<li>Stálá rychlost motoru</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,24 – 73,60 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 500kW</li>
</ul>
<a href="../fotky/ESM250.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor1] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/ESM250.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" class="kompresor"></a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="table-wrap">
<div>
<ul>
<li class="titulek">- Mazné šroubové kompresory s frekvenčním měničem, typ <b>VS7 – VS290</b></li>
<li>Proměná rychlost motoru = vyšší efektivita provozu</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,41 – 42,30 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 290kW</li>
</ul>
<a href="../fotky/GD_VS7.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor2] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/GD_VS7.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" class="kompresor"></a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="table-wrap">
<div>
<ul>
<li class="titulek">- Bezmazné šroubové kompresory řady <b>Ultima U75 – 160 PureAir</b></li>
<li>Jedinečný design – vysoká efektivita, nízký hluk</li>
<li>Proměná rychlost motoru</li>
<li>100% čistý vzduch bez oleje, splňuje ISO 8573-1 Class Zero (2010)</li>
<li>Výkon až 160kW</li>
</ul>
<a href="../fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor3] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" class="kompresor"></a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="table-wrap">
<div>
<ul>
<li class="titulek">- Bezmazné šroubové kompresory řady <b>EnviroAire S PureAir</b></li>
<li>Stálá rychlost motoru</li>
<li>Splňuje ISO 8573-1 CLASS O</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,39 – 1,76 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 8 / 10 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 15kW</li>
</ul>
<a href="../fotky/GD_EnviroAire_S_PureAir.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor4] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver EnviroAire S PureAir.jpg"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/GD_EnviroAire_S_PureAir.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver EnviroAire S PureAir" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver EnviroAire S PureAir" class="kompresor"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish something clever with `overflow: hidden;` on the content that is supposed to resize dynamically!

You can see in my example below that the image has a fixed width, and is floated right, while the text content isn't floated, but has `overflow: hidden;`, which causes it to be responsive and wrap as the container resizes.

I prefer to not use tables for only semi-tabular content, like this, if I can help it. The pattern you're describing in your example looks like a common one, often called the **Media Object**. There is a nice post that talks about it more, here: [Media Object Write-Up](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/)

It's basically just a web design pattern that has an image on one side, and some kind of text/button/whatever content on the other side.

```css
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* a clearfix, since I used floats */
.columns:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.columns__column {
  padding: 10px;
}

.columns__column--left {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.columns__column--right {
  width: 210px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}



/* just some generic stuff */
p {margin: 0;}
img {display: inline-block; max-width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="columns__column  columns__column--right">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg" alt="kitten">
  </div>
  
  <div class="columns__column  columns__column--left">
    <p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <div class="columns__column  columns__column--right">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/140.jpg" alt="kitten2">
  </div>
  
  <div class="columns__column  columns__column--left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <div class="columns__column  columns__column--right">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg" alt="kitten2">
  </div>
  
  <div class="columns__column  columns__column--left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequa.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I used your solution because you were first ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use table layout?

I came up with something like this:

```
.table-box {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
}

.table-box tr td:nth-of-type(2) {
    text-align: center;
}

.table-box img {
    height: 150px;
}
```

And the modified html:

```
<table class="table-box">

    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li class="titulek">-   Mazné šroubové kompresory systém zatíženo – odlehčeno, typ <b>ESM 2 -500</b></li>
                <li>Stálá rychlost motoru</li>
                <li>Dodávaný objem: 0,24 – 73,60 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
                <li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
                <li>Výkon až 500kW</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="../fotky/ESM250.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor1] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/ESM250.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" class="kompresor"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li class="titulek">-   Mazné šroubové kompresory s frekvenčním měničem, typ <b>VS7 – VS290</b></li>
                <li>Proměná rychlost motoru = vyšší efektivita provozu</li>
                <li>Dodávaný objem: 0,41 – 42,30 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
                <li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
                <li>Výkon až 290kW</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="../fotky/GD_VS7.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor2] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/GD_VS7.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" class="kompresor"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li class="titulek">-   Bezmazné šroubové kompresory řady <b>Ultima U75 – 160 PureAir</b></li>
                <li>Jedinečný design – vysoká efektivita, nízký hluk</li>
                <li>Proměná rychlost motoru</li>
                <li>100% čistý vzduch bez oleje, splňuje ISO 8573-1 Class Zero (2010)</li>
                <li>Výkon až 160kW</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="../fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor3] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" class="kompresor"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li class="titulek">-   Bezmazné šroubové kompresory řady <b>EnviroAire S PureAir</b></li>
                <li>Stálá rychlost motoru</li>
                <li>Splňuje ISO 8573-1 CLASS O</li>
                <li>Dodávaný objem: 0,39 – 1,76 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
                <li>Výstupní tlak: 8 / 10 bar</li>
                <li>Výkon až 15kW</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="../fotky/GD_EnviroAire_S_PureAir.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor4] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver EnviroAire S PureAir.jpg"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/GD_EnviroAire_S_PureAir.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver EnviroAire S PureAir" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver EnviroAire S PureAir" class="kompresor"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `width` of each `table-wrap` is different.  That, in combination with your `margin:0 auto` makes the left alignment appear in different areas. 
 Setting a `width` on the `div.table-wrap` gets all the text aligned to the left, with the images on the right.  I set it with to `width:100%`, and it matches with what your desired outcome sounds like.

```css
div.table-wrap {
  display: table;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

div.table-wrap div {
  display: table-row;
}

div.table-wrap ul {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.table-wrap ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

div.table-wrap ul li.titulek {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.00em;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

div.table-wrap a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

div.table-wrap a img {
  height: 150px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrap">
<div>
<ul>
<li class="titulek">- Mazné šroubové kompresory systém zatíženo – odlehčeno, typ <b>ESM 2 -500</b></li>
<li>Stálá rychlost motoru</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,24 – 73,60 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 500kW</li>
</ul>
<a href="../fotky/ESM250.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor1] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/ESM250.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" class="kompresor"></a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="table-wrap">
<div>
<ul>
<li class="titulek">- Mazné šroubové kompresory s frekvenčním měničem, typ <b>VS7 – VS290</b></li>
<li>Proměná rychlost motoru = vyšší efektivita provozu</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,41 – 42,30 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 290kW</li>
</ul>
<a href="../fotky/GD_VS7.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor2] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/GD_VS7.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" class="kompresor"></a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="table-wrap">
<div>
<ul>
<li class="titulek">- Bezmazné šroubové kompresory řady <b>Ultima U75 – 160 PureAir</b></li>
<li>Jedinečný design – vysoká efektivita, nízký hluk</li>
<li>Proměná rychlost motoru</li>
<li>100% čistý vzduch bez oleje, splňuje ISO 8573-1 Class Zero (2010)</li>
<li>Výkon až 160kW</li>
</ul>
<a href="../fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor3] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" class="kompresor"></a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="table-wrap">
<div>
<ul>
<li class="titulek">- Bezmazné šroubové kompresory řady <b>EnviroAire S PureAir</b></li>
<li>Stálá rychlost motoru</li>
<li>Splňuje ISO 8573-1 CLASS O</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,39 – 1,76 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 8 / 10 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 15kW</li>
</ul>
<a href="../fotky/GD_EnviroAire_S_PureAir.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor4] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver EnviroAire S PureAir.jpg"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/GD_EnviroAire_S_PureAir.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver EnviroAire S PureAir" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver EnviroAire S PureAir" class="kompresor"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would switch over to using tables. Makes it easier to place your images and you need less CSS. Like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/xnNk1AXJp8uSG8BfvFCj?p=preview

See my code:

```
<table>
  <tr class="table-wrap">
    <td>
<ul>
<li class="titulek">-   Mazné šroubové kompresory systém zatíženo – odlehčeno, typ <b>ESM 2 -500</b></li>
<li>Stálá rychlost motoru</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,24 – 73,60 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 500kW</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td class="img-td">
<a href="../fotky/ESM250.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor1] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/ESM250.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" class="kompresor"></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="table-wrap">
   <td>
<ul>
<li class="titulek">-   Mazné šroubové kompresory s frekvenčním měničem, typ <b>VS7 – VS290</b></li>
<li>Proměná rychlost motoru = vyšší efektivita provozu</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,41 – 42,30 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 290kW</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td class="img-td">
<a href="../fotky/GD_VS7.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor2] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/GD_VS7.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" class="kompresor"></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="table-wrap">
   <td>
<ul>
<li class="titulek">-   Bezmazné šroubové kompresory řady <b>Ultima U75 – 160 PureAir</b></li>
<li>Jedinečný design – vysoká efektivita, nízký hluk</li>
<li>Proměná rychlost motoru</li>
<li>100% čistý vzduch bez oleje, splňuje ISO 8573-1 Class Zero (2010)</li>
<li>Výkon až 160kW</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td class="img-td">
<a href="../fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor3] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" class="kompresor"></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="table-wrap">
   <td>
<ul>
<li class="titulek">-   Bezmazné šroubové kompresory řady <b>EnviroAire S PureAir</b></li>
<li>Stálá rychlost motoru</li>
<li>Splňuje ISO 8573-1 CLASS O</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,39 – 1,76 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 8 / 10 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 15kW</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td class="img-td">
<a href="../fotky/GD_EnviroAire_S_PureAir.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor4] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver EnviroAire S PureAir.jpg"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/GD_EnviroAire_S_PureAir.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver EnviroAire S PureAir" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver EnviroAire S PureAir" class="kompresor"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

.table-wrap {
 width: auto;
}

td.img-td {
  text-align: center;
}

.table-wrap ul {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.table-wrap ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.table-wrap ul li.titulek {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.00em;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.table-wrap a img {
  height: 150px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I used one of previous solutions because it is purer.